# Project depends on com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I've created a demo wear project with android studio without touching anything. In build.Gradle this error occurs, although I find curious that it lets the app compile.

> Project depends on com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.2, so it
>   must also depend (as a provided dependency) on
>   com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.2

[image]

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add

```
provided com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.2
```

to your dependencies

**EDIT:**

`provided` is deprecated now, use `compileOnly` like so:

`compileOnly com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.2`

Comment: Not work: "This dependency should be marked as provided, not compile"

Comment: Gradle DSL method not found : ''provide()'

Comment: @user2983041 sorry, typpo check again

Comment: This gives me 
`Execution failed for task ':wear:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported`

Comment: @JonasBorggren you provides wrong dependency.... take a closer look on answer once more

Comment: `provided` is deprecated on newest versions of Gradle. Please use `compileOnly`